# RubyMine 5.4 sinatra support

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rubymine

I can't get the Sinatra support to work on RubyMine 5.4. Everything runs well but i would love to have some support from the RubyMine IDE.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Should I assume you have the rack gem installed?  Seems it would be unusual for that not to be the case, but it seems to be required.  EDIT: I would guess that, if Sinatra is used in place of Rails, it wouldn't be that unusual not to have rack.

From Rubymine 5.4.3.2.1 Help:

> Gems sinatra and rack are supported With the 'sinatra' and
>   'rack' gems installed, it is possible to create and run sinatra
>   applications. Code completion, error and syntax highlighting are
>   available.

I included it in my Gemfile, did a Bundle Install, and required it.  The result is displayed.

I did no further configuration than this, so I can't think of any settings that would be causing you a problem.

You can search at JetBrains, but I didn't see a hit there myself.  You can post an issue [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/home).  Serge provides great support!  I should know, as I bug him all the time for help...

[image]

Comment: unfortunately i already tried it before posting and it doesn't work

Comment: Do you have both Sinatra and rack in the Gemfile?  Are Rubymine updates applied?  What is your Ruby level, environment, etc.?  Am I right that you don't have Rails?  Was Rubymine a fresh install or an upgrade?  I recommend you clear the cache and retry (File | Invalidate Caches & Restart Rubymine).

Comment: How is this going?  Did you solve it?  Do you have questions I can answer?

Comment: unfortunately not :( Thanks, but no more questions still waiting for a response from the JetBrains team